# algorithm for calc distances between a list of cities

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am using python and its third party library - geopy.

if I have a list of city, for example

```
cities = ["New York, NY","Chicago, IL","Denver, CO"]
```

and I've got the latitude and longitude of them:

```
location = [(40.0149856, -105.2705456), (40.7127837, -74.0059413), (41.8781136, -87.6297982), (39.737567, -104.9847179)]
```

My problem is :

1. start at 34.0522342 -118.2436849;
2. compare the distance between startpoint and cities in the list, find the place that is the
   closest.
3. from that place, find next one that is the closest[except
       the startpoint]
4. repeat until all the places are used.   get the
       total distances.

How can I write this in python? or what would the algorithm be?

Comment: I've done compare the list with the startpoint. If I found New York, for example, is the closet, I have no idea of how to compare the city to the rest in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geopy is able to calculate distances using vincenty or great_circles.  Loop through the list finding the smallest distance add that distance to the total pop off that location and repeat.
Something like:

```
total = 0  
while location != []:  
    test = float("inf")  
    for loc in location:  
        #do distance calc here set = to dist  
        if dist < test:  
            test = dist  
            temp = loc  
    total += test  
    location.remove(loc)
```

Comment: That is what I have thought. but how to loop through the list after comparing the 1st one. For example, if I found New York is the closet to the startpoint, how to check who is next? the length of the list would change

Comment: Updated my answer that should be close to what you are looking to do

Comment: What is "test = float("inf")" for?

Comment: Thank you very much, I think location.remove(loc) is what I want to get

Comment: sets test to be as big as possible thus allowing the first distance you calculate to be set to test.  There are other ways around this using flags but this way is simple and concise